# How to make option selection change button link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down list and a button. I want to make the selection of list reflects on the button link.

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5t9s2k0/)

Here is the example code:

```
<select style="float:left;">
<option value="5">$5.00 monthly</option>
<option value="10">$10.00 monthly</option>
<option value="15">$15.00 monthly</option>
<option value="20">$20.00 monthly</option>
</select>

<div id="button" style="width:100px;height:30px;float:left;background:#ccc;line-height:30px;text-align:center;margin:auto 5px;">
<a href="http://ordernow/5/">Order</a>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is when the user for example selects the second option, the button link changes to http://ordernow/10/ instead of http://ordernow/5/ and so on. Can someone inform me how do that or provide a link for a tutorial regarding this? Thank you.

Comment: Hey Jerry, don't forget to choose an answer when your problem has been solved! If it hasn't been solved, please update your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pure javascript and adding ids to some of the elements:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5t9s2k0/2/)

Here's the JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("subscription").onchange = function() {
    
    document.getElementById("order-btn").href = "http://ordernow/"+this.value+"/";
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to `select's onchange` to get the new selected option's value. And then add the value to button's href:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    $('#button > a').attr('href', 'http://ordernow/' + $(this).val() + '/');
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/o5t9s2k0/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Can use a regex to parse the end of the href so path doesn't need to be known

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var val =$(this).val();
    $('#button a').attr('href', function(_,href){
        var reg = /\/\d\/$/;        
        return href.replace(reg, '/'+val+'/');        
    });    
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8m0jct9/)**</kbd>