# How to change button URL through JS?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have been spending a lot of time researching how to change a button href dynamically in my website using JS.  I have a functioning Wordpress website, but would like to add some small additional functionality using JS to change a button's link based on a few user options.

I have researched this and found answers, but I absolutely cannot get the solutions to work on my site.

> One of the simplest solutions that should work was found here:
>   [How to make option selection change button link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146064/how-to-make-option-selection-change-button-link)

I can't understand what is different between what I am trying to accomplish and what the accepted answer proposed.  I added window.onload() to prevent the JS from running before elements were loaded.

I am trying to do something similar with the following HTML & JS code:

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="input-book-type" value="GlassCrystal">

<br><br>

<select id="select-page-size">
<option value="6x6">6" x 6"</option>
<option value="10x10">10" x 10"</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<input id="input-project-title" value="Optional Project Title">

<br><br>    

<a class="button" id="design-button" href="http://">Design Now</a>
```

**JS Code:**

```
window.onload = function() {

document.getElementById("design-button").onclick = function() {
var booktype = document.getElementById("input-book-type");
var pagesize = document.getElementById("select-page-size");
var projtitle = document.getElementById("input-project-title");

this.href = "http://test/?sessionid=guest&ref="+booktype.value+pagesize.value+"&projectName="+projtitle.value+"/";
};

}
```

**JS Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/w65c9x2d/

Comment: Do you want to change the href or redirect the page?

Comment: So do you just want to update the href only when you click the button, or do you want to update the href whenever an input is updated?

Comment: I would like to change the href on the button (id design-button)

Comment: Basically, I thought if I do it this way, after the user changes options, when they click it the href will be updated to the current status.  Avoid (avoiding unnecessary updates of the href)

Comment: What's happening when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code to change the href is correct. However, the onload function is not immediately invoked for the code to work.

```js
window.onload = function(e) {

  var booktype = document.getElementById("input-book-type");
  var pagesize = document.getElementById("select-page-size");
  var pagenum = document.getElementById("select-page-num");
  var projtitle = document.getElementById("input-project-title");

  document.getElementById("design-button").onclick = function() {
    this.href = "http://design.framesmile.com/?sessionid=guest&ref=" + booktype.value + pagesize.value + "*projectName=" + projtitle.value + " / ";
    console.log(this.href);
  };
}();// invoke the function
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="input-book-type" type="" value="GlassCrystal">

<br>
<br>

<select id="select-page-size">
  <option value="6x6">6" x 6"</option>
  <option value="10x10">10" x 10"</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<select id="select-page-num">
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<input id="input-project-title" type="" value="Optional Project Title">

<br>
<br>


<a class="button" id="design-button" href="http://test/">Design Now</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  Could you elaborate further on what exactly was going on.  I thought that the window.onload() would run immedately after the page loads.  I apologize if it is a dumb question, I am very new to JS.

Comment: Sure. Basically whats happening is you are assigning a function to the 'onload' property of the 'window' object. So, window.onload = function(){} just adds the function body. Now, the browser won't invoke the function by itself, so we have to do it ourselves. Thus, window.onload = function(){}() will immediately invoke the function after its creation. The technical term for this is IIFE if you want to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code:

```
<a href="#" id="abc">jhg</a>
<a href="#" id="myLink">jhhghj</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById("abc").href="xyz.php"; 
   return false;
};
</script>
```

I took this from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Change your button to this:

```
<button class="button" id="design-button" onclick="redirect()">Design Now</button>
```

Now instead of using a link, simply do a function that will take the inputs and change the window.location.href (or whatever method you prefer) to change the page.

```
redirect(obj) {
    window.location.href = "http://test/?sessionid=guest&ref="+booktype.value+pagesize.value+"&projectName="+projtitle.value+"/"
}
```

Obviously change it to your liking :)

Comment: **important note

You don't have to use <button> for this to work, just thought it'd be nicer than plaintext :)

Comment: Yes, in the JSFiddle it looks ugly, but on my website it looks great! :)

Comment: Well, in that case, just use <p> and style it similar to your <a> tag :)
The reason I'm avoiding <a> is simply because that has default behaviour that we want to change

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using jQuery.

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                data = $("#link").val();
                $("#frame").attr({
                    src: "http://"+data});
            });
```

When the submit  button is clicked, it changed the iframe url which changed the content of the iframe automatically.

I don't really understand what you are trying to ask, but try to modfiy the code above :)