# Append parameter to URL without refresh from referring page?

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics

**Background:**
I have two pages on my site a `Referring Page` and the `End Page`. After users click a button on the `Referring Page` they will be directed to different versions of the `End Page` based a variable stored called `pagex`. I need to append parameters to the `End Page` for tracking purposes.

Code I use on `End Page`

```
if (localStorage.getItem('pagex') === 'page_1') {
 window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/error-test/?1");
}
else if (localStorage.getItem('pagex') === 'page_2') {
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/error-test/?2");
}
else {
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/error-test/");
}
```

This was based on the solution here: [Appending parameter to URL without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828160/appending-parameter-to-url-without-refresh)

**Problem:**
While the above solution appends the correct parameter, it somehow creates two sessions in Google Analytics (eg. the first to /error-test/ and the second to /error-test/?1). This messes up analytics for tracking purposes.

Another solution I have considered but instead on the `Referring Page` include this: [How to change button URL through JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346094/how-to-change-button-url-through-js). However, the issue with such solutions is that I cannot amend the button behaviour (as this is determined by the plugin `Elementor`). The button basically redirects users to /error-test/ so all I need to do is append the right parameters behind the url.

**Question:**
I think the way to solve this involves appending parameters but from the `Referring Page` so that URLs that users are redirected to already have the required parameters (and hence no need for a refresh)? That way there will exist only one session in Google Analytics. Any advice on how I can implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: could you please extend your question with a description of your tracking setup and examples of split sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for cross domain tracking as google analytics currently doesn’t recognize the pages as joined so it created one for site A and one for site B.

See below reference for cross domain tracking

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

Its simple like this:

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?arg=123");
```